# Significato di "copione" in questo passaggio

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Quando tornai a Roma, frugai tra le carte di mio padre. Erano conservate nella casa di famiglia che avevo lasciato da anni, in volenteroso disordine, in due stipi di metallo. C’erano pile di cartelle colorate, scatole da scarpe stracolme di fogli, carta velina, giornali scompagnati, dattiloscritti, **copioni**. Speravo che avesse scritto dell’America.

Ho cercato il termine "copione" in parecchi dizionari, ma non mi sembra che quello che ho trovato, cioè, la sceneggiatura di un film o di uno spettacolo teatrale o del testo di una trasmissione radiofonica o televisiva, sia il senso di questo vocabolo nel brano sopra citato. Potreste spiegarmi che cosa vuol dire?

Comment: A me pare proprio che si riferisca a delle sceneggiature, dato il contesto ("carta velina... dattiloscritti, copioni")

Comment: Hai ragione, @DenisNardin! Adesso mi sono accorta che il padre della Mazzuco, Roberto Mazzuco (a cui si riferisce il brano), è stato un drammaturgo e ha scritto parecchie opere teatrali. Si tratta, quindi, di una domanda stupida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da Treccani per *[copione](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/copione1/)*:

> **copióne** s. m. [accr. di *copia*]. – Nel linguaggio di teatro, testo di
>   un lavoro drammatico affidato alla compagnia (un tempo manoscritto),
>   che viene distribuito per l’apprendimento e le prove agli attori
>   (oltre che al regista e al suggeritore), e dal quale vengono estratte
>   le parti staccate per i personaggi secondarî: *recitare a c., attenersi
>   al c.;* battuta non prevista dal c. (o fuori c.), improvvisata
>   dall’attore; estens. e fig.: *è sempre il solito c.;* non com., parlare,
>   agire a c., senza spontaneità, secondo quanto già stabilito in
>   precedenza, o seguendo indicazioni e prescrizioni esterne. Per
>   estens., la sceneggiatura di un film, il testo di una trasmissione
>   radiofonica o televisiva.

Nel contesto da te citato era il manoscritto detto anche sceneggiatura e serviva agli attori per prepararsi alla parte.

Secondo  [Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/copione.html):

> Copia del testo di un'opera drammatica destinata alla
>   rappresentazione, utilizzata spec. dagli attori e dal regista durante
>   le prove || Sceneggiatura di un'opera cinematografica || Testo di una
>   trasmissione radiofonica o televisiva